# setting a Polymer CSS mixin in a nested mixin

Tags: css, polymer

Polymer supports CSS mixins, which can be set like this:

```
scope1 {
  --mixin1: {
    attr1: val1;
  };
}
```

and applied like this:

```
scope2 {
  @apply --mixin1; /* sets attr1 */
}
```

Is there a way to set the value of a mixin from inside a mixin? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
scope1 {
  --mixin1: {
    attr1: val1;
    --mixin2: {
      attr2: val2;
    };
  };
}

scope2 {
  @apply --mixin1; /* sets attr1 */
  @apply --mixin2; /* is attr2 set? */
}
```

A real case of why this would be useful: Say you have an app that uses several custom components based on `paper-listbox` and `paper-item`. You would like to style all of the lists in your custom components with a different spacing and font. You could set the `--paper-listbox` and `--paper-item` mixins in a global scope. But that would affect every occurrence of the two elements relying on defaults. Instead in your custom components, you would simply `@apply --custom-list;` and set that mixin in a global `:root {--custom-list: {/*set list style, set item style*/}; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Instead of nesting mixins, refactor into selectors:

```
scope1 {
  --mixin1: {
    attr1: val1;
  };
}
scope1 scope2 {
  --mixin2: {
    attr2: val2;
  };
}
```

In the use case above, instead of `--custom-list` with nesting:

```
:root custom-list {
  --paper-input-container: {/*set list style*/};
  --paper-item: {/*set item style*/};
}
```